# Powershell and NCover

Tags: powershell, ncover

trying to call NCover 1.5.8 from PowerShell.

```
invoke-expression "ncover.console.exe nunit-console-x86.exe Test.dll /labels /xml:test.xml //x coverage.xml //reg"
```

and failed with the message "Profiled process terminated. Profiler connection not established.".

If called from cmd console,

```
ncover.console.exe nunit-console-x86.exe Test.dll /labels /xml:test.xml //x coverage.xml //reg
```

will run successfull.

Is there something different with the //reg swith for NCover in powershell?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to use `Invoke-Expression`.  From powershell, try invoking exactly the same way as in cmd

```
ncover.console.exe nunit-console-x86.exe Test.dll /labels /xml:test.xml //x coverage.xml //reg
```

If you get the same error, does it work to shell out to cmd temporarily?

```
cmd.exe /c ncover.console.exe nunit-console-x86.exe Test.dll /labels /xml:test.xml //x coverage.xml //reg
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: H, I just tried both method. They are still returing the same message. Profiled process terminated. Profiler connection not established.".